# Why does Django not allow me to have static content in my page

Tags: django

Something like:

```
{% block tab_content %}

{% endblock %}
```

renders fine but

```
{% block tab_content %}
<img src="{% static "assets/img/others/2.jpg" %}" alt="" />
{% endblock %}
```

Gives:

```
Invalid block tag: 'static', expected 'endblock'
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: do you have {% load staticfiles %}?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035736/django-load-block-for-css .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to have `{% load staticfiles %}` at the top of your template in order for the `static` tag to work.